# npm doesn't install node-gyp, error: ‘class v8::Object’ has no member named ‘ForceSet’

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, node-gyp

First project from work and got stuck with this tedious error on Ubuntu.

Currently using node -v 13.8.0, installed python 2.7.17, GCC 7.5.0

also checked node-gyp npm page and installed all python and gcc dependencies.
here is my package.json file

```
  "dependencies": {
    "apn": "^2.1.5",
    "async": "^1.5.2",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "^0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.1",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "consolidate": "^0.14.5",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "dotenv": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-validator": "^2.20.4",
    "fcm-node": "^1.2.0",
    "geocoder": "^0.2.3",
    "jimp": "^0.2.28",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^5.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.12.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.14",
    "mongoose": "^4.4.8",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^1.0.6",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "mustache": "^2.3.0",
    "node-cron": "^1.2.1",
    "node-excel-export": "^1.4.4",
    "nodemailer": "^2.3.0",
    "nodemailer-mailgun-transport": "^1.3.5",
    "nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^2.7.4",
    "qr-image": "^3.2.0",
    "randomstring": "^1.1.5",
    "request": "^2.69.0",
    "soap": "^0.23.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.3",
    "strong-soap": "^1.5.0",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^1.9.3",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^1.0.7",
    "time": "^0.12.0",
    "twilio": "^3.9.1",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "uuid": "^3.2.1",
    "ws.js": "^2.0.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.9.5"
  }
```

```
npm install

> ursa@0.9.4 install /home/shubham/Desktop/hotel/demo_hotellife_api/node_modules/ursa
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/home/shubham/Desktop/hotel/demo_hotellife_api/node_modules/ursa/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/ursaNative/src/ursaNative.o
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:192:0,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.h:10,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.cc:3:
../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h: In function ‘Nan::Maybe<bool> Nan::ForceSet(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)’:
../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:112:15: error: ‘class v8::Object’ has no member named ‘ForceSet’
   return obj->ForceSet(isolate->GetCurrentContext(), key, value, attribs);
               ^~~~~~~~
In file included from ../../nan/nan_converters.h:67:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:197,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.h:10,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.cc:3:
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h: In static member function ‘static Nan::imp::ToFactoryBase<v8::Boolean>::return_t Nan::imp::ToFactory<v8::Boolean>::convert(v8::Local<v8::Value>)’:
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:18:69: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::ToBoolean(v8::Local<v8::Context>)’
       val->To ## TYPE(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()->GetCurrentContext())          \
                                                                     ^
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:22:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘X’
 X(Boolean)
 ^

In file included from /home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:49,
                 from ../src/time.cc:5:
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:2750:44: note: candidate: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::String> v8::Value::ToString(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<String> ToString(
                                            ^~~~~~~~
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:2750:44: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
In file included from ../src/time.cc:5:0:
../../nan/nan.h:921:74: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::String::WriteUtf8(char*&, int, int, const int&)’
         length_ = string->WriteUtf8(str_, static_cast<int>(len), 0, flags);
                                                                          ^
In file included from /home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:49,
                 from ../src/time.cc:5:
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:2947:7: note: candidate: int v8::String::WriteUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char*, int, int*, int) const
   int WriteUtf8(Isolate* isolate, char* buffer, int length = -1,
       ^~~~~~~~~
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:2947:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘char*’ to ‘v8::Isolate*’
In file included from ../src/time.cc:5:0:
../../nan/nan.h: In member function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call_(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’:
../../nan/nan.h:1479:5: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     ));
     ^
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:49:0,
                 from ../src/time.cc:5:
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/node.h:180:50: note: declared here
                 NODE_EXTERN v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
                                                  ^
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/node.h:99:42: note: in definition of macro ‘NODE_DEPRECATED’
     __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../src/time.cc:5:0:
../../nan/nan.h: In member function ‘void Nan::AsyncWorker::SaveToPersistent(const char*, const v8::Local<v8::Value>&)’:
../../nan/nan.h:1533:64: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::String>, const v8::Local<v8::Value>&)’
     New(persistentHandle)->Set(New(key).ToLocalChecked(), value);
                                                                ^
In file included from /home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:49,
                 from ../src/time.cc:5:
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3547:37: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                     ^~~
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3547:37: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3550:37: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t, v8::Local<v8::Value>)
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                     ^~~
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3550:37: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
In file included from ../src/time.cc:5:0:
../../nan/nan.h: In member function ‘void Nan::AsyncWorker::SaveToPersistent(const v8::Local<v8::String>&, const v8::Local<v8::Value>&)’:
../../nan/nan.h:1539:42: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Set(const v8::Local<v8::String>&, const v8::Local<v8::Value>&)’
     New(persistentHandle)->Set(key, value);
                                          ^
In file included from /home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:49,
                 from ../src/time.cc:5:
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3547:37: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                     ^~~
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3547:37: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3550:37: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t, v8::Local<v8::Value>)
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                     ^~~
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3550:37: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
In file included from ../src/time.cc:5:0:
../../nan/nan.h: In member function ‘void Nan::AsyncWorker::SaveToPersistent(uint32_t, const v8::Local<v8::Value>&)’:
../../nan/nan.h:1545:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Set(uint32_t&, const v8::Local<v8::Value>&)’
     New(persistentHandle)->Set(index, value);
                                            ^
In file included from /home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:49,
                 from ../src/time.cc:5:
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3547:37: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                     ^~~
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3547:37: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3550:37: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t, v8::Local<v8::Value>)
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                     ^~~
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3550:37: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
In file included from ../src/time.cc:5:0:
../../nan/nan.h: In member function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::AsyncWorker::GetFromPersistent(const char*) const’:
../../nan/nan.h:1551:61: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::String>)’
         New(persistentHandle)->Get(New(key).ToLocalChecked()));
                                                             ^
In file included from /home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:49,
                 from ../src/time.cc:5:
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3594:43: note: candidate: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                           ^~~
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3594:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3597:43: note: candidate: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t)
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                           ^~~
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3597:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
In file included from ../src/time.cc:5:0:
../../nan/nan.h: In member function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::AsyncWorker::GetFromPersistent(const v8::Local<v8::String>&) const’:
../../nan/nan.h:1557:55: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Get(const v8::Local<v8::String>&)’
     return scope.Escape(New(persistentHandle)->Get(key));
                                                       ^
In file included from /home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:49,
                 from ../src/time.cc:5:
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3594:43: note: candidate: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                           ^~~
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3594:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3597:43: note: candidate: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t)
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                           ^~~
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3597:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
In file included from ../src/time.cc:5:0:
../../nan/nan.h: In member function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::AsyncWorker::GetFromPersistent(uint32_t) const’:
../../nan/nan.h:1562:57: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Get(uint32_t&)’
     return scope.Escape(New(persistentHandle)->Get(index));
                                                         ^
In file included from /home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:49,
                 from ../src/time.cc:5:
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3594:43: note: candidate: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                           ^~~
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3594:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3597:43: note: candidate: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t)
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                           ^~~
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3597:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/cassert:44:0,
                 from /home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/node_object_wrap.h:26,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:51,
                 from ../src/time.cc:5:
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h: In destructor ‘virtual Nan::ObjectWrap::~ObjectWrap()’:
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:24:25: error: ‘class Nan::Persistent<v8::Object>’ has no member named ‘IsNearDeath’
     assert(persistent().IsNearDeath());
                         ^
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:2222:0,
                 from ../src/time.cc:5:
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h: In member function ‘void Nan::ObjectWrap::MakeWeak()’:
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:67:18: error: ‘class Nan::Persistent<v8::Object>’ has no member named ‘MarkIndependent’
     persistent().MarkIndependent();
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/cassert:44:0,
                 from /home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/node_object_wrap.h:26,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:51,
                 from ../src/time.cc:5:
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h: In static member function ‘static void Nan::ObjectWrap::WeakCallback(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::ObjectWrap>&)’:
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:124:26: error: ‘class Nan::Persistent<v8::Object>’ has no member named ‘IsNearDeath’
     assert(wrap->handle_.IsNearDeath());
                          ^
../src/time.cc: At global scope:
../src/time.cc:12:20: error: ‘Handle’ has not been declared
   static void Init(Handle<Object> target) {
                    ^~~~~~
../src/time.cc:12:26: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
   static void Init(Handle<Object> target) {
                          ^
../src/time.cc: In static member function ‘static void Time::Init(int)’:
../src/time.cc:16:20: error: ‘target’ was not declared in this scope
     Nan::SetMethod(target, "time", Time_);
                    ^~~~~~
../src/time.cc:16:20: note: suggested alternative: ‘tzset’
     Nan::SetMethod(target, "time", Time_);
                    ^~~~~~
                    tzset
../src/time.cc: In static member function ‘static Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE Time::Localtime(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
../src/time.cc:87:64: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::IntegerValue()’
     time_t rawtime = static_cast<time_t>(info[0]->IntegerValue());
                                                                ^
In file included from /home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:49,
                 from ../src/time.cc:5:
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:2774:40: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<long int> v8::Value::IntegerValue(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int64_t> IntegerValue(
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:2774:40: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
../src/time.cc: In static member function ‘static Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE Time::Mktime(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
../src/time.cc:141:103: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Int32Value()’
     tmstr.tm_sec   = Nan::Get(arg, Nan::New("seconds").ToLocalChecked()).ToLocalChecked()->Int32Value();
                                                                                                       ^
In file included from /home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:49,
                 from ../src/time.cc:5:
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:2778:40: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<int> v8::Value::Int32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int32_t> Int32Value(Local<Context> context) const;
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:2778:40: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
../src/time.cc:142:103: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Int32Value()’
     tmstr.tm_min   = Nan::Get(arg, Nan::New("minutes").ToLocalChecked()).ToLocalChecked()->Int32Value();
                                                                                                       ^
In file included from /home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:49,
                 from ../src/time.cc:5:
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:2778:40: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<int> v8::Value::Int32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int32_t> Int32Value(Local<Context> context) const;
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:2778:40: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
../src/time.cc:143:101: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Int32Value()’
     tmstr.tm_hour  = Nan::Get(arg, Nan::New("hours").ToLocalChecked()).ToLocalChecked()->Int32Value();
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:49,
                 from ../src/time.cc:5:
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:2778:40: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<int> v8::Value::Int32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int32_t> Int32Value(Local<Context> context) const;
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:2778:40: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
../src/time.cc:144:106: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Int32Value()’
     tmstr.tm_mday  = Nan::Get(arg, Nan::New("dayOfMonth").ToLocalChecked()).ToLocalChecked()->Int32Value();
                                                                                                          ^
In file included from /home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:49,
                 from ../src/time.cc:5:
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:2778:40: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<int> v8::Value::Int32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int32_t> Int32Value(Local<Context> context) const;
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:2778:40: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
../src/time.cc:145:101: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Int32Value()’
     tmstr.tm_mon   = Nan::Get(arg, Nan::New("month").ToLocalChecked()).ToLocalChecked()->Int32Value();
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:49,
                 from ../src/time.cc:5:
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:2778:40: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<int> v8::Value::Int32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int32_t> Int32Value(Local<Context> context) const;
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:2778:40: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
../src/time.cc:146:100: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Int32Value()’
     tmstr.tm_year  = Nan::Get(arg, Nan::New("year").ToLocalChecked()).ToLocalChecked()->Int32Value();
                                                                                                    ^
In file included from /home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:49,
                 from ../src/time.cc:5:
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:2778:40: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<int> v8::Value::Int32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int32_t> Int32Value(Local<Context> context) const;
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:2778:40: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
../src/time.cc:147:113: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Int32Value()’
     tmstr.tm_isdst = Nan::Get(arg, Nan::New("isDaylightSavings").ToLocalChecked()).ToLocalChecked()->Int32Value();
                                                                                                                 ^
In file included from /home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:49,
                 from ../src/time.cc:5:
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:2778:40: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<int> v8::Value::Int32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int32_t> Int32Value(Local<Context> context) const;
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/v8.h:2778:40: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
../src/time.cc: At global scope:
../src/time.cc:156:21: error: variable or field ‘init’ declared void
   static void init (Handle<Object> target) {
                     ^~~~~~
../src/time.cc:156:21: error: ‘Handle’ was not declared in this scope
../src/time.cc:156:21: note: suggested alternative: ‘rand_r’
   static void init (Handle<Object> target) {
                     ^~~~~~
                     rand_r
../src/time.cc:156:34: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
   static void init (Handle<Object> target) {
                                  ^
../src/time.cc:156:36: error: ‘target’ was not declared in this scope
   static void init (Handle<Object> target) {
                                    ^~~~~~
../src/time.cc:156:36: note: suggested alternative: ‘tzset’
   static void init (Handle<Object> target) {
                                    ^~~~~~
                                    tzset
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:49:0,
                 from ../src/time.cc:5:
../src/time.cc:159:21: error: ‘init’ was not declared in this scope
   NODE_MODULE(time, init)
                     ^
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/node.h:610:36: note: in definition of macro ‘NODE_MODULE_X’
       (node::addon_register_func) (regfunc),                          \
                                    ^~~~~~~
../src/time.cc:159:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE’
   NODE_MODULE(time, init)
   ^~~~~~~~~~~
../src/time.cc:159:21: note: suggested alternative: ‘int’
   NODE_MODULE(time, init)
                     ^
/home/shubham/.cache/node-gyp/13.8.0/include/node/node.h:610:36: note: in definition of macro ‘NODE_MODULE_X’
       (node::addon_register_func) (regfunc),                          \
                                    ^~~~~~~
../src/time.cc:159:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE’
   NODE_MODULE(time, init)
   ^~~~~~~~~~~
time.target.mk:113: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/time/src/time.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/time/src/time.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/shubham/Desktop/hotel/demo_hotellife_api/node_modules/time/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.0.0-37-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/shubham/Desktop/hotel/demo_hotellife_api/node_modules/time
gyp ERR! node -v v13.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN Trump@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN Trump@1.0.0 No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ursa@0.9.4 (node_modules/ursa):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ursa@0.9.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! time@0.12.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the time@0.12.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/shubham/.npm/_logs/2020-05-07T11_31_00_132Z-debug.log
```

**Things I tried**
downgraded to various node versions like to v8.11.0- same problem

downgraded node to v6.9.5 as mentioned in package.json file. but there started getting various 
JS versioning errors like '...Object' not supported. not supporting es6.

installed node-gyp globally, still nothing resolved.

please help me on my maiden command of my maiden project

Answer (score 10):

This works for me

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
npm-check-updates -u
npm install
```

Comment: Easiest solution I've ever come across for fixing node-gyp issues!

Comment: Solved my problem 3 years later.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you have is the **time** package which is outdated https://www.npmjs.com/package/time.

There are some different solutions depending on why are you using that package, you could use a different library/package to handle dates and time, but you will probably need to refactor some code.

Try removing this dependency from the **package.json**, `"time": "^0.12.0"` and running `npm install` again to see if it runs correctly.

Then change the dependency to use an updated fork of `time` like this one
https://github.com/riyadshauk/node-time. Your `time` dependency on **package.json** should look like this

```
"dependencies": {
 "time": "github:riyadshauk/node-time"
}
```

Your full dependencies should be like this (assuming you haven't installed/removed anything since your question), the only change is on `time`, the rest is the same.
I used node v13.7.0

```
 "dependencies": {
  "apn": "^2.1.5",
  "async": "^1.5.2",
  "bcrypt-nodejs": "^0.0.3",
  "body-parser": "^1.15.1",
  "compression": "^1.6.2",
  "consolidate": "^0.14.5",
  "cookie-parser": "^1.4.1",
  "cors": "^2.8.4",
  "dotenv": "^2.0.0",
  "express": "^4.13.4",
  "express-validator": "^2.20.4",
  "fcm-node": "^1.2.0",
  "geocoder": "^0.2.3",
  "jimp": "^0.2.28",
  "jsonwebtoken": "^5.7.0",
  "moment": "^2.12.0",
  "moment-timezone": "^0.5.14",
  "mongoose": "^4.4.8",
  "mongoose-unique-validator": "^1.0.6",
  "morgan": "^1.7.0",
  "multer": "^1.3.0",
  "mustache": "^2.3.0",
  "node-cron": "^1.2.1",
  "node-excel-export": "^1.4.4",
  "nodemailer": "^2.3.0",
  "nodemailer-mailgun-transport": "^1.3.5",
  "nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^2.7.4",
  "qr-image": "^3.2.0",
  "randomstring": "^1.1.5",
  "request": "^2.69.0",
  "soap": "^0.23.0",
  "socket.io": "^2.0.3",
  "strong-soap": "^1.5.0",
  "swagger-jsdoc": "^1.9.3",
  "swagger-ui-express": "^1.0.7",
  "time": "github:riyadshauk/node-time",
  "twilio": "^3.9.1",
  "underscore": "^1.8.3",
  "uuid": "^3.2.1",
  "ws.js": "^2.0.23"
 }
```

Comment: thank you so much! This is the only solution for the latest version of MacOSx and node

Comment: What if I don't use the "time" library? How do I found out which package is causing the issue?